# Threading in WPF operations

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I Have some *operations* (i work with WPF). I wont to run they in a separate **thread**.
How can I do it?

Example:

```
foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)) 
{
    foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, txtFile.Text)) 
    {
        lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f);
    }
    DirSearch(d);
}
```

Comment: Please specify your problem and what you want with more details!

Comment: So you just want to run the following code in its own thread and just return back so your app can just continue operating?  What is DirSearch... your function shown here to basically recursively get files within respective sub-folders?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using .NET 4, you can use [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Just an example in C# .NET 4 Console App:

```
internal class Program
    {
        private static readonly object listLockObject = new object();
        private  static readonly IList<string> lstFilesFound = new List<string>();
        private static readonly TxtFile txtFile = new TxtFile("Some search pattern");
        private static string sDir = "Something";


        public static void Main()
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(Directory.GetDirectories(sDir), GetMatchingFolderAndDoSomething);
        }

        private static void GetMatchingFolderAndDoSomething(string directory)
        {
            //This too can be parallelized.
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(directory, txtFile.Text))
                {
                    lock (listLockObject)
                    {
                        lstFilesFound.Add(f);
                    }
                }

            DirSearch(directory);
        }

        //Make this thread safe.
        private static void DirSearch(string s)
        {
        }

        public class TxtFile
        {
            public TxtFile(string text)
            {
                Text = text;
            }

            public string Text { get; private set; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with WPF and need to go multithreaded, you will have to start by [Separating the UI from the business logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel), otherwise you will end up with an endless chain of `Dispatcher.Invoke()` calls.

As another answer also states, refer to the Task Parallel Library to ease development of multithreaded applications, but be aware that WPF UIElements' Properties can only be accessed by the thread that created them (usually called the Dispatcher Thread).